# How to capitalize a pandas object in a column without converting it into string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to capitalize a pandas object in a list without converting it into string for matching purpose.

This is the datset:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| [apple pie, banana milkshake, chocolate ice cream] |  |
| [chicken noodles, lamb chops, lime juice] |  |

I'm expecting column B:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| [apple pie, banana milkshake, chocolate ice cream] | [Apple Pie, Banana Milkshake, Chocolate Ice Cream] |
| [chicken noodles, lamb chops, lime juice] | [Chicken Noodles, Lamb Chops, Lime Juice] |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) in list comprehension for uppercase first letter for each word, because [`str.capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) convert first letter only in first word:

```
df['Column B'] = [[y.title() for y in x] for x in df['Column A']]
df['Column C'] = [[y.capitalize() for y in x] for x in df['Column A']]
print (df)
                                            Column A  \
0  [apple pie, banana milkshake, chocolate ice cr...   
1          [chicken noodles, lamb chops, lime juice]   

                                            Column B  \
0  [Apple Pie, Banana Milkshake, Chocolate Ice Cr...   
1          [Chicken Noodles, Lamb Chops, Lime Juice]   

                                            Column C  
0  [Apple pie, Banana milkshake, Chocolate ice cr...  
1          [Chicken noodles, Lamb chops, Lime juice]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
# import required module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': [['apple pie', 'banana milkshake', 'chocolate ice cream'], ['chicken noodles', 'lamb chops', 'lime juice']],
})

# create column b, c
df['Column B'] = df['Column A'].apply(lambda x: [y.title() for y in x])
df['Column C'] = df['Column A'].apply(lambda x: [y.capitalize() for y in x])
```